# Kendo UI Mobile - 'Reset' ScrollView to first page?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I have a ScrollView that contains 2 pages and I have also created a back button that just goes back to the home page.

What I'm trying to do is this: 
If the ScrollView is on the 2nd page when the back button is hit, I want to effectively 'reset' this ScrollView so that if the user comes back they will always see the 1st page of the ScrollView first.

I can set the position of the ScrollView fine by setting -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px), which shows the content of the first page.  The problem I have is with the list items that show which page you're on.  Upon clicking the back button, using jQuery I have removed the **km-current-page** class from the 2nd list item in the km-pages ol and added it to the 1st one.  So from this:

```html
<ol class="km-pages">
  <li></li>
  <li class="km-current-page"></li>
</ol>
```

to this:

```html
<ol class="km-pages">
  <li class="km-current-page"></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```

However, when I come back to this ScrollView, something is undoing this and setting the current page back to how it was before hitting the back button i.e. the 2nd page.

Is there something in Kendo UI Mobile that would be undoing my code of switching the class around or is there just a 'reset' setting I can call?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try using the scrollTo() method of the ScrollView and just scroll to the first page?

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/mobile/scrollview#methods-scrollTo